# Is there a way of validating json schema in Oracle R12.2 while consuming a payload over an ORDS service?

Tags: json, oracle, oracle-ords

I have a requirement to port a service hosted on AWS lamdba to Oracle ORDS. Currently we do a schema validation on the AWS using python. Is it possible to do the same in Oracle ORDS.

Answer (score 0):

In 12c it's possible to create an "IS JSON" constraint. Create a (global temporary table) with such a constraint and insert the payload. It will throw an exception if it's not valid json. It's very well described in Tim Halls blog [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/json-support-in-oracle-database-12cr1). This can be done as part of a handler in ORDS.